# How do I properly state the set of all functions between two sets using the axiom schema of comprehension/separation?

Tags: logic, set-theory

> Axiom schema of separation:  $\forall A \exists B \forall x (x \in B \iff x \in A \land \phi)$

> Set of all functions from $D$ to $C$: $ \{ F : \forall d \in D \exists c \in C ( \langle d, c \rangle \in F \land \forall c' \in C (\langle d,c' \rangle \in F \iff c =c') \}$

**My question is:** in order to formally state $\phi$, do we need it to first state the existence of $C,D$? i.e., do we define $\phi$ as: $\color{red}{\exists D \exists C} \forall d \in D \exists c \in C ( \langle d, c \rangle \in F \land \forall c' \in C (\langle d,c' \rangle \in F \iff c =c')$?

Comment: If you want to describe the set of functions from $D$ to $C$, then these I would guess are given and you don't need to state existence in the formula (if they didn't exist, there wouldn't even be a set of functions between them). What you do need is specify the set $A$, namely the set of functions $B$ is the set of all elements of some other set $A$ such that [here the formula you wrote down, without $\exists D\exists C$]

Comment: @Alessandro thanks for the comment! the question comes from the specific case where it is unclear whether the set $C^D$ exists. In that case, wouldn't we need to not take for granted the existence of $C,D$? Or would that be proven separately, letting $C,D$ be free in the specification of $A$? And thank you for the clarification on specifying $A$

Comment: Noticed a small problem with my last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that $C,D$ can be fixed or quantified depending on the statement you want to prove. If you want to prove

> Given $C,D$, there is a set of all functions $D\rightarrow C$.

In this case, existence is assured by the premise that $C,D$ are given and so you only need to specify some set $A$ (depending on $C,D$) and $\phi$ such that $$C^D=\{X\in A|\phi(X)\}$$
Otherwise, if the statement you want to prove is

> For all $C,D$, there is a set of all functions $D\rightarrow C$.

Then $C,D$ are not fixed and need to be quantified, so then you take the statement from the previous point and add at the beginning $$\forall C\forall D\cdots$$
You don't use $\exists$ because that would mean

> There are $C,D$ such that the set of all functions $D\rightarrow C$ exists.

Which is true, but weaker than the true statement with $\forall$. Also, $\phi$ cannot contain quantifiers over $C,D$, because for $\phi$ these two sets are fixed (but $\phi$ can depend on $C,D$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!

Comment: You're welcome :)